# How to manually acknowledge rabbitmq message using Camel rabbitmq

Tags: java, rabbitmq, apache-camel, spring-camel

We are using camel for rabbitmq producers and consumers.
We create consumers with autoAck as false and we feel currently camel manages it internally to acknowledge that message after the consumer route`s processor is completed.

What we want is a handle to send a basicAck to rabbitmq.

like we can do if we were using a spring based integration

`long deliveryTag = envelope.getDeliveryTag();`

`channel.basicAck(deliveryTag, false);`

please let us know if there is already a way to do so using camel-rabbitmq

Comment: Hi @devansh-arora, were you able to find a solution for this in the meantime? If so, could you please share it as an answer here? :)